# Field injection with @Inject in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsr330

I've got some strange behavior in working of `@Inject` in Spring.
This example works well:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private SomeBean someBean;

    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public String showHome() {
        System.out.println(someBean.method());
        return "home";
    }
}
```

But if I replace `@Autowired` with `@Inject`, `showHome` method will throw `NullPointerException` because `someBean` is `null`. The same thing with setter injection. But with constructor injection both `@Autowired` and `@Inject` works well.

Why does it happen?

I'm using Spring 4.3.1.
My dependencies in `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Comment: Constructor Injection works as long as you have only one constructor with or without any annotations. So basically Spring does not recognize the `@Inject` at all. Do you have right dependencies on your classpath? Please post your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`

Comment: @AliDehghani You are right about pom.xml. I've noticed that I have dependency javaee-web-api with provided scope. I replaced it with javax.servlet-ap and javax.inject, and now both annotation works well. Post your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @VitalyVitrenko You can answer your own question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring supports JSR-330 standard annotations, you just need to put the relevant jars in your classpath. If you're using maven, add the following to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Why Constructor Injection Works?

---

As of [Spring 4.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements_3), It is no longer necessary to specify the `@Autowired` annotation **if the target bean only defines one constructor**. Since you have only one constructor, required dependencies will be injected no matter which annotation you're using.

Also checkout this post on [why field injection is evil](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/).